# Importing @fastify/oauth2 with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, fastify

I'm trying to import and register the plugin `@fastify/oauth2`. I'm using the following dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.15.5",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.7",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.21",
    "pino-pretty": "^9.4.0",
    "rimraf": "^4.4.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsc-alias": "^1.8.4",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fastify/cors": "^8.2.0",
    "@fastify/oauth2": "^7.0.1",
    "@trpc/client": "^10.18.0",
    "@trpc/server": "^10.18.0",
    "@types/luxon": "^3.2.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "fastify": "^4.15.0",
    "luxon": "^3.3.0",
    "mysql2": "^3.2.0",
    "zod": "^3.21.4"
  }
```

And this is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "composite": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

But when I try to register the plugin like this:

```
server.register(fastifyOauth2, {
  name: 'facebookOAuth2',
  credentials: {
    client: {
      id: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
      secret: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET
    },
    auth: fastifyOauth2.FACEBOOK_CONFIGURATION
  },
  // register a fastify url to start the redirect flow
  startRedirectPath: '/login/facebook',
  // facebook redirect here after the user login
  callbackUri: 'http://localhost:1337/login/facebook/callback'
});
```

Typescript gives me the following error:

`TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 2 of 3, '(plugin: FastifyPluginAsync<FastifyOAuth2Options, RawServerDefault, FastifyTypeProviderDefault, FastifyBaseLogger>, opts?: FastifyRegisterOptions<...> | undefined): FastifyInstance<...> & PromiseLike<...>', gave the following error.     Argument of type 'FastifyOauth2' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FastifyPluginAsync<FastifyOAuth2Options, RawServerDefault, FastifyTypeProviderDefault, FastifyBaseLogger>'`.

Is this an error in the library or am I just using it wrong?

I tried importing it like the following and while they all resolved they all gave the same error:

```
import fastifyOauth2 from '@fastify/oauth2';
import { fastifyOauth2 } from '@fastify/oauth2';
import * as fastifyOauth2 from '@fastify/oauth2';
```

Answer (score 1):

The [client id and secret](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-oauth2/blob/master/types/index.d.ts#L79) in the Oauth2 plugin config must be of type `string`, while you are providing variables of type `string | undefined` (process.env variables).

You need to add type assertion to the env variables in your config to "tell" the compiler to handle it as string: `process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID as string`

The plugin registration code will look something like:

```
server.register(fastifyOauth2, {
  name: 'facebookOAuth2',
  credentials: {
    client: {
      id: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID as string,
      secret: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET as string,
    },
    auth: fastifyOauth2.FACEBOOK_CONFIGURATION
  },
  // register a fastify url to start the redirect flow
  startRedirectPath: '/login/facebook',
  // facebook redirect here after the user login
  callbackUri: 'http://localhost:1337/login/facebook/callback'
});
```